# Removing item from an array of items does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, setstate

I am trying to remove an item from a list of items, but it does not seem to work. I have a page where I can add entries dynamically and items can be removed individually too. Adding seems to just work fine.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-heyrovsky-r7b4k

### Code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: "",
      values: []
    };
  }

  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event.currentTarget.value });
  };

  onAdd = () => {
    this.setState({
      value: "",
      values: [...this.state.values, this.state.value]
    });
  };

  onRemove = index => {
    console.log(index);
    let { values } = this.state;
    let filteredIDs = values.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
      values: filteredIDs
    });
  };

  render() {
    let { values, value } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <input
          required
          placeholder="xyz@example.com"
          value={value}
          onChange={this.onChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.onAdd}>Add</button>
        <div>
          <ul className="email-list-holder wd-minus-150">
            {values.map((value, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                {value}
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.onRemove(index)}
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                >
                  Remove
                </button>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `but it does not seem to work` you should've noticed what actually happens and mentioned that in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let filteredIDs = values.splice(index, 1);` returns the removed item after it removes it from `values`

you'll want

```
onRemove = index => {
  let { values } = this.state;
  values.splice(index, 1);
  this.setState({
    values
  });
```

> tested and works on your codesandbox :p

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the working demo for you

https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-snow-kkudc**

You have to change the below line.

```
let filteredIDs = values.splice(index, 1);
```

Use it instead of above one.

```
let filteredIDs = values.filter((x, i)=> i!==index);
```

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using wrong javascript method when remove the item.

> [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method changes the contents of an array by removing or replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements
>
> [Slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included) where begin and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.

Replace

```
 let filteredIDs = values.splice(index, 1);
```

With

```
 let filteredIDs = values.slice(index, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the removed part of the array instead of the correct one.

```
    onRemove = index => {
      console.log(index);
      let { values } = this.state;
      values.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({
          values
        });
  };
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You set the removed items as the new values. This will fix it.

```
onRemove = index => {
console.log(index);
let { values } = this.state;
let filteredIDs = values.splice(index, 1);
this.setState({
  values: values
});
```

};

Answer (score 0):

`splice` returns the deleted elements and you are setting the removed elements. You can directly do:

```
values.splice(index, 1);
this.setState({
  values,
})
```

You can also use `uniqueId` in order to give each new element a `uniqueId` this would help in filtering logic.

Here's how I may have structured the state and methods:

```
this.state = {
  values: {
    todo1: {
      value: 'a'
    },
    todo2: {
      value: 'b'
    },
  }
}


// Addition

this.setState({
  values: {
    ...this.state.values,
    uniqueId: {
      value: 'New Value from input'
    }
  }
});


// Deletion

const stateValues = this.state.values;

delete stateValues[uniqueId];

this.setState({
  values: stateValues,
});
```